# Find a particular character in a text file?

Tags: c++, c

I have a text file which looks like as following:

Fulladder

3 inputs

INPUT(A)

INPUT(B)

INPUT(Cin)

Now i need to know the names of input which are 'A', 'B' and 'Cin' here. I am able to open the file and read it. But i am getting strange output. My code is following:

```
// Finding the names of inputs
    if(buffer[i] == 'I' && buffer[i+1]=='N' && buffer[i+2]=='P' && buff     er[i+5]=='(')
    {
        if( buffer[i+7]==')' ) // i.e. single digit Input name
        {
            char inputName[1];
            inputName[0] = buffer[6];
            string name(inputName);
            cout<<"\n Name of inputs:  "<<inputName[0]<<"\n";
        }

        else if( buffer[i+8]==')' ) // To check is the value of value of inputs consists of one digit or two digit
        {

            char inputName[2];
            inputName[0] = buffer[6]; inputName[1] = buffer[7];
            string name(inputName);
            cout<<"\n Name of inputs:  "<<inputName[0]<<inputName[1]<<"\n";
        }

        else if( buffer[i+9]==')' ) // i.e. three digit Input name
        {
            char inputName[3];
            inputName[0] = buffer[6]; inputName[1] = buffer[7]; inputName[2] = buffer[8];
            string name(inputName);             
            cout<<"\n Name of inputs:  "<<inputName[0]<<inputName[1]<<inputName[2]<<"\n";
        }


    }
```

But i am getting the following output:

Name of inputs:  a

Name of inputs:  a

Name of inputs:  add

Comment: Are you going to have a different branch for every possible length of variable name?

Comment: There are other (many other) ways to search strings.  For starters, look at `strstr()` and `strcmp()`.  The method you are using is certainly useful, but not exactly the way you are using it.

Comment: You mean the input name? Input name can be of one, two or maximum three characters. And, it will always be enclosed in brackets ().

Comment: No, I am being general.  You are searching strings by looking at each character.  It might be useful to use the string search functions I mentioned.  Add `strtok()` to the other two, and you can do just about any type of string search needed.

Comment: @ryyker: I can find the string "INPUT" but i want to read the things inside brackets. So after finding the string "INPUT" how do i find the character/characters inside () ?

Comment: `if(strstr(buffer, "(A)") != NULL){//you have found your A input}`.  Then use `strtok()` to parse that string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you copy the characters from the buffer, you are forgetting to offset then by `i`. For example:

```
inputName[0] = buffer[6];
```

should be:

```
inputName[0] = buffer[i+6];
```

Comment: thanks alot. It was really a silly mistake but took a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string getpart(string &input){
    string pre("INPUT(");
    string ret("");
    size_t len = pre.length();
    size_t pos = input.find(pre);
    if(pos == 0){
        pos = input.find(")", len);
        ret = input.substr(len, pos - len);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    string input, part;
    for(int i=0; i<3 ; ++i){
        cin >> input;
        part = getpart(input);
        cout << part << endl;
    }
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string getpart(string &input, const char *pre, const char *post){
    string ret("");
    string::size_type pre_pos = input.find(pre), len = string(pre).length();
    if(pre_pos != string::npos){
        pre_pos += len;
        string::size_type post_pos = input.find(post, pre_pos);
        if(post_pos != string::npos)
            ret =  input.substr(pre_pos, post_pos - pre_pos);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    string input, part;
    getline(cin, input);
    part = getpart(input, "INPUT(", ")");
    cout << part << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the counter "i" which probably represents the beginning of the current line, but you're reading from fixed indexes when you actually pull the characters out of the array.

For example, for the one-character case, you should be reading from "buffer[i+6]" instead of "buffer[6]".

That being said, I very highly recommend that you write some functions to figure out how to parse the lines so that you don't have to write code for every possible length of the value.

Comment: Yeah it got solved but when i trying to print the names using `string name` as present in my code, i am getting strange outputs

Answer (score 1):

@user2440724 - Regarding your questions to my comments:  Look at (run) this small example of using `strtok()` for example.  Put a break point in and look at the value of buf as you step through:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[]="INPUT(A)"; //simulated line buffer
    char *buf;

    buf = strtok(buffer, "(");//strip away INPUT and (
    buf = strtok(NULL, ")");//Capture contents of ( )
    //do something with "A", read next line buffer

    return 0;
}
```